# How do I databind a toolbar to collection of different kinds of controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm building a toolbar in WPF that needs to host a mix of buttons and dropdown menus. The buttons and menus may be interspersed in any order.

I would like to populate this toolbar by binding against an ObservableCollection.

My main question is how do I express in Toolbar.ItemTemplate that there are different kinds of objects that should be created? You can assume that the ViewModels in the ObservableCollection contain a property to distinguish which are intended as buttons and which are menus. (Or should these be separate ViewModels themselves?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ToolBar class has an [ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) property which you can point at a template selector. Write a custom template selector which tells the toolbar which template to use based on the type of the underlying item.

The MSDN documentation for the property has an example.